# This is weird , get_user_meta and get_post_meta inside plugin class Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I don't know why get_user_meta or get_post_meta is not working on my code when using a variable, but when i use fixed value. It gives me the correct output.

NOTE: It is confirmed that the variable has a value.

Here is the test code i used inside the plugin class public function:

```
    if( $args['source'] == 'User SignUp') {
        $userid = 0;
        
        $userid = $args['referral_wp_uid'];
        
       
        $member_pin = get_user_meta($userid, 'membership-pin', true);
        
        //It works when i use this fixed value 60 or any correct user id
        //$member_pin = get_user_meta('60', 'membership-pin', true);

        //I check if the result of get_user_meta is empty or not
        if (empty($member_pin)) {
            $args['amount'] = '1';
        }else{
            $args['amount'] = $member_pin;
        }
        
        //Check if $userid is empty - It actually has a value because it is added on the $args['reference_details']
        if (empty($userid)) {
            $args['reference_details'] = $args['reference_details'] . '1';
        }else{
            $args['reference_details'] = $args['reference_details'] . $userid;
        }
        
    }
```

When i used it on theme functions.php or header.php it work but inside the plugin class it does not work

This is the function i modified inside the class:

```
public function save_referral_unverified($args=array()){ // protected
    /*
     * UNVERIFIED STATUS
     * @param array
     * @return boolean
     */
    global $indeed_db;
    $keys = array(
                    'referral_wp_uid',
                    'campaign',
                    'affiliate_id',
                    'visit_id',
                    'description',
                    'source',
                    'reference',
                    'reference_details',
                    'amount',
                    'currency',
    );

    $args = apply_filters( 'uap_public_filter_insert_referral_args', $args );

    foreach ($keys as $key){
        if (!isset($args[$key])){
            return FALSE;
        }
    }

    /// NEGATIVE REFERRALS?
    if ($args['amount']<0){
        $args['amount'] = 0;
    }

    /// EMPTY REFERRALS
    $general_settings_data = $indeed_db->return_settings_from_wp_option('general-settings');
    if (empty($general_settings_data['uap_empty_referrals_enable'])){
        ///don't insert referrals with 0$
        $min = 0.01;
        if ($args['amount']<$min){
            return;
        }
    }
    /// EMPTY REFERRALS
    
    //EDITED: MLM Sign Up Bonus Value based on Membership Pins
    if( $args['source'] == 'User SignUp') {
        $userid = 0;
        
        $userid = $args['referral_wp_uid'];
        
       
        $member_pin = get_user_meta($userid, 'membership-pin', true);
        
        //It works when i use this fixed value 60 or any correct user id
        //$member_pin = get_user_meta('60', 'membership-pin', true);

        //I check if the result of get_user_meta is empty or not
        if (empty($member_pin)) {
            $args['amount'] = '1';
        }else{
            $args['amount'] = $member_pin;
        }
        
        //Check if $userid is empty - It actually has a value because it is added on the $args['reference_details']
        if (empty($userid)) {
            $args['reference_details'] = $args['reference_details'] . '1';
        }else{
            $args['reference_details'] = $args['reference_details'] . $userid;
        }
        
    }

    $args['date'] = current_time( 'Y-m-d H:i:s' );//date('Y-m-d H:i:s', time());
    $args['status'] = 1;//unverified
    $args['payment'] = 0;//unpaid
    $args['parent_referral_id'] = '';// empty for moment, will be updated if it's case
    $args['child_referral_id'] = '';//always will be empty
    $referral_id = $indeed_db->save_referral($args);
    if ($referral_id){
        $indeed_db->update_visit_referral_id($args['visit_id'], $referral_id);
        if (get_option('uap_mlm_enable')){
            $limit = get_option('uap_mlm_matrix_depth');
            $first_child_username = $indeed_db->get_wp_username_by_affiliate_id($args['affiliate_id']);

            $theAmount = $args['amount'];
            $uap_mlm_use_amount_from = get_option('uap_mlm_use_amount_from');
            if ($uap_mlm_use_amount_from && $uap_mlm_use_amount_from=='product_price' && isset($args['product_price'])){
                $theAmount = $args['product_price'];
            }

            $this->mlm_do_save_referral_unverified($args['affiliate_id'], $referral_id, 1, $limit, $theAmount, $first_child_username, $referral_id);
        }
    }
    return TRUE;
}
```

This the plugin class structure:

```
class Referral_Main{
    protected static $user_id;
protected static $affiliate_id;
protected static $source;
protected static $campaign;
protected static $visit_id = 0;
protected static $currency;
protected static $special_payment_type = '';
protected static $coupon_code = '';

public function __construct($user_id=0, $affiliate_id=0){

}

public function save_referral_unverified($args=array()){ // protected
  //this is where i added the code get_user_meta code
}
  
}
```

Also i tried wpdb get_var and it also not giving me the output. I hope you can help me. Thanks

Comment: There is a typo here `plublic function nameofthefunction`

Comment: Hi! i just name type it here only but there's an actual public function inside the class plugin. I actually know the problem and its weird. When i used fixed value like this : $member_pin = get_user_meta('60', 'membership-pin', true); it work and give out but when i used variable like this $member_pin = get_user_meta($user_id, 'membership-pin', true); it does not work. $user_id came from this array item $args['refferal_wp_uid']

Comment: Can you try to echo the $user_id variable on the page to check if it is true?

Comment: Yes it has a value i change it to $userid, i just noticed that $user_id is declared on the class "protected static $user_id;" i thought this is the problem so i change it to $userid but still not working. Its getting weirded cause when i use fixed value get_user_meta is working and giving me the output

Comment: Then probably `$args['refferal_wp_uid']` is empty or incorrect

Comment: i edited the content of my question. You can check it. I can confirm that $args['refferal_wp_uid'] has a value